# Laravel: export Excel File in a given path?

Tags: php, laravel, export, export-to-excel, maatwebsite-excel

Api

```
Route::get('UserExport', function (UserRequest $request) {
    return Excel::download(new UserExportExcel($request->id), 'UserReport.xlsx');
});
```

UserExportExcel

```
 private $id;

    public function __construct(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }


    public function collection()
    {
        $filePath = storage_path('app/Users/'.$this->id . '.xlsx'); //file name is 15.xlsx which is the id +.xlsx
        User::all()->downloadExcel(
            $filePath,
        );
    }
```

I'm trying to export my excel file without using model!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done I solve it using this method directly from API (i specify the full path of my excel file (path+name),and downloaded using Response::download

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

Route::get('UserExport', function (UserRequest $request) {
    $filePath = storage_path('app/Users/' . $request->id . '.xlsx');
    return Response::download($filePath);
});
```

Comment: while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: hello , thank you for your note i will follow it !